# How can multiple values in a cell be validated against multiple cells at once?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

I'm trying to validate default selections for a user:

```
**Table 1** -- Displays values
Cell value = 1
Cell value = 2
Cell value = 3
Cell value = 4
Cell value = 5

**Table 2** -- Displays values selected by user
Cell value = 2, 4, 5
```

Is there a way to compare the values from multiple cells in Table 1 to the values listed in a single cell in Table 2?

Thank you.

Comment: SQL database, despite superficial resemblances, are not spreadsheets. They don't have cells (and columns and rows are *vastly different* to each other)

Comment: Can it be done, yes it can.  The better question is how to do it which opens a whole different conversation.

Comment: If you have to do it in this way (not using another table) you can use `table2.value LIKE '%,' + table1.value + ',%'` and make sure table2.value starts and ends with `,`